# undefined method `whitelist_attributes=' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Have been following rails guide, While running the code:

```
rails generate model Comment commenter:string body:text article:reference
```

I get the following error:

```
/Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing': undefined method `whitelist_attributes=' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Have tried searching for similar questions and one suggestion was to remove

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false
```

Have searched the whole app directory and couldn't find any occurrence of such code.

Rails Version: 5.2.1
Ruby Version: 2.5.1

```html
$ bundle exec rails generate model Comment
config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:

  * development - set it to false
  * test - set it to false (unless you use a tool that preloads your test environment)
  * production - set it to true

      invoke  active_record
Traceback (most recent call last):
 49: from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
 48: from script/rails:6:in `require'
 47: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
 46: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
 45: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
 44: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
 43: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
 42: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
 41: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/generate/generate_command.rb:26:in `perform'
 40: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/generators.rb:276:in `invoke'
 39: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
 38: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
 37: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `invoke_all'
 36: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
 35: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `each'
 34: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
 33: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
 32: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
 31: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/group.rb:133:in `_invoke_from_option_orm'
 30: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/group.rb:266:in `_invoke_for_class_method'
 29: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/shell.rb:68:in `with_padding'
 28: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/group.rb:277:in `block in _invoke_for_class_method'
 27: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:115:in `invoke'
 26: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
 25: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `invoke_all'
 24: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
 23: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `each'
 22: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
 21: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
 20: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
 19: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/rails/generators/active_record/model/model_generator.rb:22:in `create_migration_file'
 18: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/generators/named_base.rb:92:in `table_name'
 17: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/generators/named_base.rb:201:in `pluralize_table_names?'
 16: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
 15: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
 14: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
 13: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
 12: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
 11: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:328:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
 10: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
  9: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
  8: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
  7: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `execute_hook'
  6: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:62:in `with_execution_control'
  5: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `block in execute_hook'
  4: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `instance_eval'
  3: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:123:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
  2: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:123:in `each'
  1: from /Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:124:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/Users/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing': undefined method `whitelist_attributes=' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Did you add the `protected_attributes` gem to your `Gemfile`?

Comment: Are you upgrading Rails or copying something from somewhere else? Attribute whitelisting was removed in Rails 4 with the advent of strong parameters. https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-3-2-to-rails-4-0-active-record

Comment: @spickermann no I haven't added protected_attributes to Gemfile.

Comment: @elliotcm i am a newbie getting started. I am not upgrading nor have copied something. Have setup one controller and one model. And trying to add another model through generators.

Comment: Do you have an `Article` model in your application?

Comment: Does the same error happen when you use `bundle exec rails generate model Comment ...` to run the command?

Comment: Yes. I tried the code and get the same error.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh yes I do and also have a controller named Article which works.